# Firebase Facebook аутентификация

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-android

Пытаюсь реализовать у себя вход в приложение с помощью Firebase Facebook, по примеру официальной документации сделал следующие [шаги](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login). Разместил кнопку на своем главном экране, при нажатии на которую открывается мой аккаунт Facebook в диалоговом окне, с предложением продолжить как - Моя учетная запись.
Но после того как нажимаю на данное предложение, выскакивает `Authentication failed`.
На данный момент реализовал у себя вход с помощью Google/Email аутентификации.
Уже перепробовал несколько вариантов из разных туториолов, не выходит как надо, поэтому решил откатиться назад и начать так скажем с чистого листа.
Сразу же скажу, что кнопка в xml есть и facebook_app_id в строковых ресурсах прописан. Также всё корректно в самой консоли firebase/facebook.

Код входа на данный момент следующий:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnReset;
    private LoginButton facebookLogin;
    private SignInButton googleSignInButton;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth googleFirebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        googleSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);
        facebookLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);

        googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        // Initialize FirebaseAuth
        googleFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class)));
        btnReset.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class)));
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //authenticate user
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,     getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.google_sign_in:
                signIn();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Constants.RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == Constants.RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed
                Log.e(Constants.SIGN_IN, "Google Sign In failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(Constants.SIGN_IN, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        googleFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(Constants.SIGN_IN, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(Constants.SIGN_IN, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(Constants.SIGN_IN, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста **правильно** добавить facebook авторизацию.

Comment: Проверьте, что включена авторизация в самой FireBase. Вы точно указываете верные данные для логина?=)

Comment: @IvanVovk да, всё верно + я думаю иначе бы, не открывалось окно facebook'a

Comment: @Inkognito возможно у вас не отрабатывает intent, ну раз не переходит в другое активити. Я так понимаю у вас логиниться, но всё таки остаётся экран login'a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну я на скорую руку пробовал, вроде должен заработать вход. Немного модифицировал Ваш же код, так как понял именно в этом загвоздка, привинтить уже к существующему функционалу дополнительно ещё 1 метод входа:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button btnSignUp;
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnReset;
private LoginButton facebookLogin;
private SignInButton googleSignInButton;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final String TAG = "FacebookLogin";
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    googleSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);
    facebookLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    facebookLogin.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    facebookLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
        }
    });

    googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    firebaseAuthWithEmailAndPassword();
}

private void firebaseAuthWithEmailAndPassword() {
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class)));
    btnReset.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class)));
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, task -> {
            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                // there was an error
                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    });
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(Constants.SIGN_IN, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
        Log.d(Constants.SIGN_IN, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(Constants.SIGN_IN, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.google_sign_in:
            signIn();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Constants.RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == Constants.RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed
            Log.e(Constants.SIGN_IN, "Google Sign In failed.");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(Constants.SIGN_IN, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Опять же выскакивает диалоговое окно с моей учётной записью - нажимаю продолжить, кнопка меняется уже на log out + в самой консоли firebase отображается что есть новый пользователь с fb. Но как мне перейти на другой экран по нажатию на log in?

Comment: Добавил условие else, попробуйте так.